# DateTime only inserting Date in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I'm passing a `DateTime` property as a field in a recently created `DataRow` through `NewRow()`, then I am updating the corresponding DataTable. All other properties of this row are inserted correctly except for the `DateTime` one - only the `Date` component is there and the `Time` is shown as `00:00:00` . The field in the database is also declared as `datetime`.

How can I fix this?

Edit: Adding code, this is how I am creating the row and passing the dateTime.

```
CyberCafeDataSet.RentaDeMaquinaDataTable tablaRentaDeMaquina = cyberCafeDataSet.RentaDeMaquina;    
CyberCafeDataSet.RentaDeMaquinaRow registroRentaDeMaquina = (CyberCafeDataSet.RentaDeMaquinaRow)tablaRentaDeMaquina.NewRow();
    registroRentaDeMaquina.horaInicio = DateTime.Now;
```

Then I'm inserting the row:

```
tablaRentaDeMaquina.AddRentaDeMaquinaRow(registroRentaDeMaquina);
            rentaDeMaquinaTableAdapter.Update(tablaRentaDeMaquina);
```

Comment: How are you inserting? Code would be nice.

Comment: Could you please post the C# for your insertion?

Comment: Which data provider are you using?

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a parameterized query make sure the type is `SqlDbType.DateTime`.

In other words:

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter( "@mydate", SqlDbType.DateTime );
p.Value = DateTime.Today;

command.Parameters.Add( p );
```